# Magento2: Get all orders using REST API?

Tags: magento2, orders, rest-api

I want to get all orders using REST Api.
I am using this code but it's not returning any result.

**Request:**

```
$this->get('rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=entity_id');
```

**Response:**
[image]

How to get all orders using REST Api?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution for this. I passed my request like:

`$this->get('rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria=entity_id');`

and for getting all orders without any filter. Use below code:

`$this->get('rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria');`

Comment: I tried it using admin token. Is there is any way to use customer token?

Comment: @Jsparo30 ```curl -X POST "https:/yourdomain.test/rest/default/V1/integration/customer/token" \ 
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d '{"username":"CustomerLogin", "password":"CustomerP@ssw"}'```

Answer (score 4):

Ideally next request must be valid to get all orders

```
$this->get('rest/V1/orders');
```

But you get error instead

```
{"message":"%fieldName is a required field.","parameters":{"fieldName":"searchCriteria"}}
```

Error occurred because request is processed by

```
\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface::getList(\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteria $searchCriteria)
```

and `$searchCriteria` argument is required.

You can skip value for this parameter. Next request must be valid too.

```
$this->get('rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria');
```

Comment: $this->get('rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria=all'); return all feilds But i want to get only specific feilds.
How can filters desire feild?